# How to get cell name and row id when changing a table using mindmup / editable-table

Tags: jquery

There is a database. Need an opportunity to edit it. I want to implement this with https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table

When changing the table, a request is sent:

```
$('#myTable td').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    $.post( "script.php", { value: newValue })
        .done(function( data ) {
                alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        }); 
    ;
});
```

In this regard, the question:

How to find out which cell was changed?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to give the cells a data-row and data-col attribute, e.g.

```html
<table id="chart_data_table" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-row="0" data-col="0">Category</td>
                                        <td data-row="0" data-col="1">Dataset 1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-row="1" data-col="0">Category 1</td>
                                        <td data-row="1" data-col="1" data-type="number">10</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-row="2" data-col="0">Category 2</td>
                                        <td data-row="2" data-col="1" data-type="number">8</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Then, you can get the cell and row by...

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Make the data table editable
            // https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            $('#data_table').editableTableWidget();
            
$('#data_table td').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
// get the row
console.log($(evt.currentTarget).data('row'))
// get the col
console.log($(evt.currentTarget).data('col'))

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mindmup/editable-table/master/mindmup-editabletable.js"></script>

<table id="data_table" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td  data-row="0" data-col="0">Category</td>
                                        <td data-row="0" data-col="1">Dataset 1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-row="1" data-col="0">Category 1</td>
                                        <td data-row="1" data-col="1" >10</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-row="2" data-col="0">Category 2</td>
                                        <td data-row="2" data-col="1" >8</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```